# Angular Material 5 elements not rendered properly

Tags: angular, button, angular-material, placeholder

I am having some issues rendering Angular Material my app. On one page of the application it renders fine, but in another submodule it doesnt. (So, yes, I have imported the material css) I believe it has something to do with the import order of my imports, but I'm not sure. I am not able to reproduce it in any plunkers :/

The two elements Im using and their problems:

1. Button: Looks OK, but color="primary" doesnt apply color
2. Input field: Looks OK, but placeholder doesn't float
3. I tried adding a MatDatePicker in the same component, and it didnt work neither.
4. All other elements in the application works fine

Html:

```
  <form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="onRegistration()">
    <mat-form-field>
      <input matInput 
             placeholder="Username">
    </mat-form-field>
    <mat-form-field>
      <input matInput placeholder="Password">
    </mat-form-field>
    <button mat-raised-button color="primary">Submit</button>
  </form>
```

This is my shared module:

```
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MaterialComponentsModule,
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  declarations: [NavbarComponent, FooterComponent],
  exports: [
    CommonModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MaterialComponentsModule,
    NavbarComponent,
    FooterComponent,
    FormsModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    JwtModule
  ],
```

This is my material components module:

```
  imports: [
  ],
  exports: [
    MatInputModule,
    MatFormFieldModule,
    MatMenuModule,
    MatIconModule,
    MatCardModule,
    MatDialogModule,
    MatProgressSpinnerModule,
    MatTabsModule,
    MatExpansionModule,
    MatDatepickerModule,
    MatSnackBarModule,
    MatButtonModule
  ],
```

I have tried to switch the order of MatInputModule/MatFormFieldModule. In my feature module I am only importing SharedModule

```
imports[SharedModule]
```

Comment: You need to include the material theme CSS if you didn't

Comment: I have, like I said, it is working in other parts of the application, just not this module.